# How can i make 10 similar division inside a row using bootstrap class. (e.g "col-lg-2")

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap classes. I don't want to use write custom css.
So, How can divide 10 division with similar width. All division should occupies full width of row

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
        // i need 10 div with similar width
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside bootstrap's source, in the `variables` file, there is a variable named `@grid-columns` (`$grid-columns` if you're using the sass version), simply change it to 10 and recompile bootstrap.

If you need a mix between 10 & 12 columns, use 60 cols and multiply accordingly

You might also want to take a look `grid-gutter-width`, `grid-float-breakpoint` and all the `screen-*` sizes which will probably need to be adapted to fit you needs.

ICYMI: here is the link to the less compiler page http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this can't be accomplished without creating custom CSS or a custom Bootstrap version. What could work is making 12 columns of .col-md-1 and leaving the outer most left and right columns empty.

Comment: I have to agree with you this is the best solution. Unless the user wants this globally in which case they could go to the bootstrap website and generate a template for 10 columns

Comment: Also a good solution possibly @Enzero, but like you said it depends on the user's wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use custom version of bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system set @grid-columns = 20 and use col-sm-2 10 times